# Pybind11 compilation with python3-config not working

Tags: c++, python-3.x, pybind11

I want to integrate a simple C++ function into Python using Pybind11. 
Consider the following simple example of a dummy function:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

// Dummy function: return a vector of size n, filled with 1
std::vector<int> generate_vector(unsigned int n)
{
    std::vector<int> dummy_vector;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) dummy_vector.push_back(1);
    return dummy_vector;
}

// Generate the python bindings for this C++ function
PYBIND11_PLUGIN(example) {
    py::module m("example", "Generate vector of size n");
    m.def("generate_vector", &generate_vector, "Function generates a vector of size n.");
    return m.ptr();
}
```

I store this code in a function called example.cpp
I use Python 3.5.2 with Anaconda. Following the [official documentation](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/basics.html),
I compile the script follows:

```
c++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -I /Users/SECSCL/anaconda3/include/python3.5m `python-config --cflags --ldflags` example.cpp -o example.so
```

I do not know exactly what the 'python-config' part stands for, but I know it causes a problem. I have tried three options:

1. python-config: This results in a clang error, linker command failed
2. python3-config: Same problem as with python-config
3. python3.4-config: This actually works and creates an example.so file. But when I try to load it from python3.5, I obtain the error

   Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread

In summary, my question is: How do I compile my code so that I can load it from python3.5? Or more precisely: what do I have to replace the 'python-config' statement with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your example going on my macOS Sierra early 2015 MacBook Pro.

I used your `example.cxx` code without any changes.

Before you compile the module, you have to ensure that the anaconda environment is active, so that the compilation command invokes the correct `python-config` command.

In my case, this was done with: `source ~/miniconda3/bin/activate` -- you obviously have to replace `miniconda3` with `anaconda3`.

Now double-check that your compile command will invoke the correct `python-config` by doing: `which python3.5-config` -- this should show you that it's using your anaconda3 `python3.5-config`.

Now you can invoke compilation as follows:

```
c++ -O3 -shared -std=c++11 -I $HOME/build/pybind11/include \
-I $HOME/miniconda3/include/python3.5m \
`python3.5m-config --cflags --libs` -L $HOME/miniconda3/lib/ \
 example.cpp -o example.so
```

Note that I had to add the include path to my pybind11 checkout, specified the exact `python-config` version (3.5m), changed the `--ldflags` to `--libs` so that `python-config` would not add the `--stack-size` link parameter which will cause errors, and finally that I added an `-L` for the miniconda3 (anaconda in your case) directory containing the `libpython3.5m.dylib`

After this, I could do:

```
$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import example
>>> v = example.generate_vector(64)
>>> print(v)
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

... which is pretty neat!

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem. I had issues with the python - config configuration.